# Какая лучше структура проекта

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования, service

Для одного проекта хочу создать папку service, и отдельно папку process, в service будут находиться классы сервисов post, get, и все запросы просто перенаправлять в классы из папки process фактически одной строкой будет каждый сервис. serivce-userService.class, process-userProcess.class примерно так. Еще хочу создать папку vo или dto для объектов которые будут приниматься или отправляться в ответ.
Как лучше сделать? проект будет не маленький.

Comment: что такое vo? Вряд ли этот вопрос относится к сервисам или шаблонам проектирования, скорее просто к организации кода. Также что значит все запросы будете перенаправлять из папки process?

Comment: Сорри, vo это value object. Перенаправлять имеется ввиду я получать запросы и отправить в process. В классе userService есть метод getThemes с таким же урлом, в нем принимается объект с несколькими полями, я просто вызываю метод getThemes в userProcess,  и то что он вернёт верну в ответе на запрос

Comment: а вы используете спринг или пишите на обычных сервлетах?

Comment: Использую Jax rs

Comment: хм, то есть JavaEE, ну вообще в целом вы мыслите верно, насчёт названий пакетов можно спорить, но мне кажется в этом случае, на вкус и цвет фломастеры разные. Мне как человеку близкому со спринг легче воспринимать, что методы внешнего взаимодействия GET, POST агрегированы в пакете controller, а логика сосредоточена в service. Тот подход, с тем, что вы собираетесь сделать методы в одну строку мне кажется верным, однако классы DTO, я бы всё таки использовал на уровне контроллеров, а в сервисах передавал и возвращал обычные модели.

Comment: @komdosh что значит обычные модели?

Comment: Не dto, а просто объекты

Comment: Разве dto это не просто объекты, там ведь только данные.

Comment: Ну, я подразумевал, что у DTO, только одна задача, быть промежуточным объектом, между сервером и клиентом, а для работы приложения используется другой класс.

Comment: А в чем проблема если передавать тот же dto в process?